# org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.exceptions.ConstraintException is not supporting in Grails 4.0.8?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am in upgrading process from **Grails 2.0.8** to **Grails 4.0.8**.
Supporting gradle version: **Gradle 5.1.1**

What would be replacement for importing package of

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.exceptions.ConstraintException
```

?
Because this package is not being supported in upgraded project?
Moreover,
Is  org.codehaus.groovy pacakge has been obsolete in Grails 4.0.x?

Answer (score 0):

> Because this package is not being supported in upgraded project?

The package does not exist in Grails 4.

> Moreover, Is org.codehaus.groovy pacakge has been obsolete in Grails
> 4.0.x?

Yes.  We removed the `org.codehaus...` packages from Grails quite a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Scott Brown. How can i import this exception class then likewise ConstraintException in our upgraded class?

Comment: "How can i import this exception class then likewise ConstraintException in our upgraded class? " - There shouldn't be anything in the system that is throwing the exception that doesn't exist.  Can you describe what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok! got it. Thanks @Jeff Scott Brown